# How to use moment.js to format the v-model data from a vuetify v-text-field (type:time)?

Tags: vue.js, time, momentjs, vuetify.js

I have this element:

```html
<v-text-field
  label="Choose a time"
  type="time"
  mask="time"
  step="1800"
  prepend-inner-icon="access_time"
  v-model="expiryTime"
  :rules="[v => !!v || 'Time is required']"
  required
  @change="getTime"
></v-text-field>
```

I want to trigger the `getTime` method to convert the `v-model` value into a `h:mm` format. As I've been testing I have entered `12:00 pm` each time as the value for `expiryTime` and have done the following:

```
getTime(){
  alert(moment().format('h:mm')) //returns current time in x:xx format
  alert(this.expiryTime); // Returns '1200'
  alert(moment(this.expiryTime).format('h:mm')); // returns '4:26, expect 12:00
  alert(moment(this.expiryTime, 'h:mm')); // returns 'Sat Aug 17 2019 12:00:00 GMT-0600', expect 12:00
```

Basically I'm getting some unexpected values and I don't know why. If I can get the current time in the top alert I am rather confused about how formatting the `expiryTime` data the same ways ends up being `4:26`. And the final alert returns the entire time with the date and etc.

Can someone please explain how I can convert the `expiryTime` data to be in h:mm format properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`moment(String)` constructor](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) takes either a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string, or an [RFC2822 date time string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3). If neither of those standards are used, the format must be specified as the second argument of the constructor.

`expiryTime` (`1200`) is in the form of `hmm`, but you had specified `h:mm`, which would've required a colon between the hour and minutes for `moment` to parse the date correctly. The fix is to remove the colon.

```js
console.log(moment(1200, 'hmm').format('h:mm'))
console.log(moment(135, 'hmm').format('h:mm'))
console.log(moment(2001, 'hmm').format('h:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```